# Get closest image attr("src") jQuery

Tags: jquery

The following code is working fine but I need the `attr("src")` of the closest image I tried in the following way and it didn't work yet.

```
$(".delimg").click(function () {
var $button = $(this);
var myString = $button.closest('.swipe-image').find('img').attr("src");
var avoid ="http://20percents.com/backend/uploads/";
myString = myString.replace(avoid,'');
$("#getnew").val(myString);
});
```

And the following way is working but without closest, picking the first value

```
$(".delimg").click(function () {
var myString = $('.swipe-image').attr("src");
var avoid ="http://20percents.com/backend/uploads/";
myString = myString.replace(avoid,'');
$("#getnew").val(myString);
});
```

How to fix the closest issue?

HTML:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e27r8/603/

**Update1: How about with onchange and trigger**

```
$(".delimg").on('change', function () {
var myString = $('.swipe-image').attr("src");
var avoid ="http://20percents.com/backend/uploads/";
myString = myString.replace(avoid,'');
$("#getnew").val(myString).join());
}).trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) will find an matching ancestor element, in your case the `img` is not a ancestor of the `button`.

You can use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find a common parent then use [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to fetch the target element

```
var myString = $button.closest('.swiper-slide').find('img').attr("src");
```

Another way is to use the logic that the `img` is the previous sibling of the `button`s parent so

```
var myString = $button.parent().prev('img').attr("src");
```

Comment: Can you please have a look at the editing question "Update 1"

Comment: @lock what are you trying to achieve

Comment: Also, to add/remove the image src to the `textbox` id `#getnew` Thanks

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Arun's solution could be:

```
$(".delimg").click(function () {
    var myString = $(this).parent().prev().attr("src");
    var avoid ="http://20percents.com/backend/uploads/";
    myString = myString.replace(avoid,'');
    $("#getnew").val(myString);
});
```